# find is undefined causing antd Tag to be empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, find, antd

I'm facing a problem where my "AntTag" component is empty when .find() resolves to undefined if the "ids" array is of "Null" value as there isnt a "Null" value to find in "departments". I need a way to allow me to display "None" if it is undefined. I have tried to do a if-statement to change the name[i] = "None" if it is null, however, it did not work. I have also tried to return **name ? {name} : "None"** inside  however it did not work as well. Can anyone please help me?

```
    if (_.isArray(ids)) {
      return ids.map((id) => {
        let name = this.state.departments.find((x) => x.id === id)?.name;
        console.log(name);
        return (
          <AntTag className=' cursor-pointer' color='magenta'>
            {name}
          </AntTag>
        );
      });
    }

    return '';
  }
```

[AntTag issue when name is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p65gp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work by changing the line to use `or` operator:

```js
const name = this.state.departments.find((x) => x.id === id)?.name || "None";
```